# gRPC - Procedures for many Clients without deadlocks in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, grpc

Let's say that I've a c# code that delivery a List set of tasks with props to a client:

```
public override Task<MyTasksResult> GetMyTasks(MyTasksRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
  return Task.FromResult(GetMyTasks(request, context));
}

private MyTasksResult GetMyTasks(MyTasksRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
  List<MyTask> list = _CoreService.GetMyTasks(request.MyTokenToFind);
  MyTasksResult t = new MyTasksResult();
  t.TaskList.AddRange(list);
  return t;
}
```

And let's say that I don't want to make this async method, because the full set of tasks should come in at most 50 ms.
But anyway, 50ms it's A LOT of time! So the main question is:
Will this code release the gRPC to receive more requests of tasks from another clients in the same GetMyTasks method?

I'm concernd since Thread.Sleep(x) can create a deadlock: would a sleep or lock on the "_CoreService.GetMyTasks" make it happen? Or since I've already set a Taks.FromResult at the begining I'm free of that?!
Thks.

Comment: I would vote for the async as well, and if you are worried about how long it takes, what about server streaming and return each result as it is available

Comment: I see. Thank you for your comment! I'm changing the way of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want to but I think you should make it async. If the code goes into a live environment where the server could be slowed down by network traffic or any number of other issues then suddenly your code might stop working. Your customer will report a problem and you'll have a difficult time trying to replicate it.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I'll take it into consideration. But the main question would be about how gRPC will MultiThread my Procedure... Will it make a new Thread and let it go to the end, or will it lock the GetMyTask procedure until it finishes?